# Copy entire Excel row into form fields

Tags: php, html

I got Excel with 4 columns: Complete name, celphone, city, and comments. And I have HTML/PHP form to send ADF format email.

At the moment I'm copying each cell and paste in each form field. How I can improve my code to copy a row from Excel and paste it in 1 time on my form fields?

I mean I need to detect `/n` to change form field or something like that? This is part of my actually form

```html
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="customer_contact_prospect" class="control-label">Nombre completo del prospecto <strong class="text-danger">*</strong></label>
    <input type="text" id="customer_contact_prospect" name="customer_contact_prospect" class="form-control required">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy and paste a range of data from excel into a text area.  The information you've given is insufficient to be used in a mailer, but here's how to extract the excel information:

HTML Form input:

```
<textarea name="excel_info"></textarea>
```

Receiving PHP script:

```
<?php
$raw_data = $_POST['excel_info'];
$name = array();

$rows = explode("\n", $raw_data);
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $column = explode("\t", $row);
    $name[] = $column[0];
}

// iterate through $name array and do whatever you need with the names
// note: no data cleansing has been done; you are responsible for cleaning your own data.
```

If you're wanting to grab a specific column using javascript, an example using the jquery library for javascript:

```
var temp = ('#customer_contact_prospect').val().split("\t");
var name = temp[0];  // assuming name is the first column

// optionally put it in a hidden input id="name"
$('#name').val(name);
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but i didnt explain well my main problem. I mean if i copy entire row from excel or google sheet's and i paste into my input field on html, i got the entire row in one field, i think i need some js function to take "/n" space and change to another input field

Comment: Ok, you tagged it as php, not JavaScript. It’s the same idea, just different command to do it. In JavaScript, you just split on \t.  Are you using jquery?